# Virtual host subdomain with a IP address as the server name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

So I have a virtual host setup that is working but it is an internal server so we have no domain name for it. So under my server name I just have the IP Address and it works fine, however now I need to setup a subdomain and apache doesn't seem to be cooperating. Below essentially what I am trying to do but with the IP address removed. Any idea how this can be done?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 111.111.111.111
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName payment.111.111.111.11
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just as a note, if it's a local IP address there is no need to obscure it.

Comment: Not local, just using the default IP digital ocean gives out :p

Comment: sorry, I must have misread the question :P

Comment: `payment.111.111.111.11` is _not_ a valid host name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to achieve this is by using a different port:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 111.111.111.111
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public/">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ServerName 111.111.111.111
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I set the port **8000** as an example, in order to avoid *side effects* by using "reserved ports" you might check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), so you can choose any unassigned one.

Don't forget to add the

**Listen 8000**

directive so the webserver attends for connections on that specific port, and also, it is convenient to add the trailing backslash within the tag:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
```